# Задать главную страницу htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Как задать стартовую страницу/главную в htaccess?

Comment: здрасте. **DirectoryIndex index.php**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать главной страницей файл menu.html:

```
DirectoryIndex menu.html
```

[Источник](https://hosting.nic.ru/support/htaccess.shtml)